# No funciona la decisión en el jButton

Tags: java

Deseo que si el spinner adquiere el valor 182135 y la seleccion del jRadioButton2 me muestre la pantalla de inicio de sesion, pero sino que siga con la de CandidatoVote.

```
CandidatoVote windows = new CandidatoVote();
Inicio_sesion nuevo = new Inicio_sesion();

laEdad = (int)(jSpinner.getValue());
    if(jRadioButton1.isSelected() || jRadioButton2.isSelected()){

         if(laEdad == 182135){
              nuevo.setVisible(true);
              this.setVisible(false);  
         }else{
              windows.setVisible(true);
              this.setVisible(false);   
         }


  }else{ 
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe llenar todos los campos \n",
            "¡AVISO!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }



}
```

Comment: En que clases están basados `CandidatoVoto` y `Inicio_sesion`? (Por consistencia recomiendo preferir `InicioSesion`).

Answer (score 0):

> Deseo que si el spinner adquiere el valor 182135 **y** la seleccion
>   del jRadioButton2 me muestre la pantalla de inicio de sesion, pero
>   sino que siga con la de CandidatoVote.

Por lo que leo pones un Y  por lo que en código sería && el operador lógico.
Lo único que tendrías que cambiar es el **||** por **&&**.

---

```
CandidatoVote windows = new CandidatoVote();
Inicio_sesion nuevo = new Inicio_sesion();

laEdad = (int)(jSpinner.getValue());
if(laEdad == 182135 && jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
    nuevo.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);  
}else if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){ 
    windows.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false); 
}else{
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe llenar todos los campos \n",
        "¡AVISO!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

---

```
if(laEdad == 182135 && jRadioButton2.isSelected())
```

Si el valor del Spinner (laEdad) tiene el valor de 182135 **Y** el jRadioButton2 está seleccionado, si esto no se cumple llegará a la segunda pregunta

```
else if (jRadioButton1.isSelected())
```

Si al menos tiene seleccionado jRadioButton1 entonces abrirá **windows** (clase CandidatoVote).

**SINO** (Ninguno de los dos botones está seleccionado) entonces manda el mensaje